# IL generics - what rules exist for when !T is used vs !0?

Tags: .net, generics, cil

I'm writing an IL static analysis tool, and I'm having a hard time understanding the rules governing how generic type parameters are referenced:

take this IL (from the [`IList<T>` interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/5y536ey6.aspx)):

```
.property instance !T Item(
    int32 index
)
{
    .get instance !0 System.Collections.Generic.IList`1::get_Item(int32)
    .set instance void System.Collections.Generic.IList`1::set_Item(int32, !0)
}
```

Why is the `!0` there instead of `!T`?  I presume they're equivalent as far as the VM goes, it just seems odd to use positional references at all when you're guaranteed to have the names.

**Update:** an additional case, from KeyedCollection.ctor:

```
IL_0037:  newobj instance void class System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<!TKey,!TItem>::'.ctor'(class System.Collections.Generic.IEqualityComparer`1<!0>)
IL_003c:  stfld class System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<!0,!1> class System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2<!0,!1>::dictionary
```

Comment: I don't see this.  Are you sure it isn't just a bug in your disassembler?

Comment: Hm, it's definitely something the disassembler (in this case monodis) is generating.  Mono.Cecil (which appears to be much more by-the-book metadata-wise) shows, e.g.: stfld System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2<TKey,TItem> System.Collections.ObjectModel.KeyedCollection`2<TKey,TItem>::dictionary

Comment: @HansPassant What are you using to show you the IL?

Answer (score 4):

In the [Common Language Infrastructure standard](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/netframework/aa569283.aspx), [Partition II - Metadata and File Format](http://download.microsoft.com/download/1/5/4/1546A0C9-A650-4CE4-B056-36EC09C4CFC0/Partition_II_Metadata.zip), clause 7.1 "Types" it states:

```
Type ::=        Description
--------        -----------
'!'             Generic parameter in a type definition, accessed by index from 0
```

So short answer: because it's in the spec.

Long answer: This is speculation on my part, but basically, most IL commands are stack-based and use positional references as parameters all the time.  That said, it makes sense that positional references are used for generics, in order to maintain common patterns/usage mechanisms in IL.

Comment: @svick It's not, it's used for declaration only.  The point of having the name in the metadata is to preserve the name of the type parameter, but where it's *used*, it's accessed by position.

Comment: that's still pretty confusing.  !T is used in the declaration for the property but it's referring to the same generic parameter that !0 does.  Should I just assume that they're totally interchangeable?

Comment: @toshok No, the specification doesn't say that you can use `!T` when *referencing* generic type parameters.  It only says you can use `!T` when *declaring* them.  It's easy enough to create a map for a type to handle this.

Comment: I probably should have included more cases above.  let me edit to add some actual IL instructions.

Comment: @toshok I kind of see what you mean now, let me see if I can get more from the spec.